# Как исправить ошибку 'A non well formed numeric value encountered'?

Tags: php, laravel

Использую версию 5.2

При попытке вывести любую из переменных ( $pages, $portfolios, $services, $peoples , $menu ) через helper 'dd' появляется **"ErrorException in VarCloner.php line 298:**
**A non well formed numeric value encountered"**

Предполагаю, что это как -то связано со временем. Поля 'created_at' и 'updated_at' созданы с типом 'timestamp', по умолчанию Null и заполнены вставленными датами.

Index.Controller

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Page;
use App\Service;
use App\Portfolio;
use App\People;


class IndexController extends Controller
{
    //
    
    public function execute(Request $request) {
     
     $pages = Page::all();
     $portfolios = Portfolio::get(array('name','filter','images'));
     $services = Service::where('id','<',20)->get();
     $peoples = People::take(3)->get();
     
     $menu = array();
     foreach($pages as $page) {
      $item = array('title' =>$page->name,'alias'=>$page->alias);
      array_push($menu,$item);
    }
    dd($menu);

    
    return view('site.index');
  }
    
}
```

Проблема решилась переключением версий php c 7.1 * 64 на 7.0 64. МуSQL остался тот же 5.5.64

С чем связаны эти изменения?

Цитата из оф документации:
Новые ошибки уровней E_WARNING и E_NOTICE были добавлены при использовании некорректных строк с операторами, ожидающими числа (+ - * / ** % << >> | & ^) и их эквивалентами с присваиванием. Ошибка уровня E_NOTICE выдается, когда строка начинается с цифр, но далее содержит не цифровые символы, и ошибка уровня E_WARNING выдается тогда, когда строка вообще не содержит цифр.

Как решить эту ошибку используя php 7.1 ?

Comment: Ошибка в VarCloner.php, при чем тут этот код?

Comment: Эта ошибка была связана именно с версией php. VarCloner на 298 стр ` self::$hashMask ^= hexdec(substr(spl_object_hash($obj), self::$hashOffset, PHP_INT_SIZE));`   [ссылка](https://kirkizh.ru/2018/02/php7-non-numeric-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать так, чтобы в арифметических операциях участвовали только цифры. То есть убедиться, что в каждой переменной, которая участвует в выражении, находится именно число, а не непонятно что.

В крайнем случае сменить версию php или добавить явное приведение типа:

```
$c = '';
$d = 1 + (int)$c;
```

Отдельный случай, когда возникает такая ошибка - это когда в одном выражении используется конкатенация и арифметика, например `'string' . 1 + 2 . 'string'`. В этом случае арифметическое выражение надо брать в скобки.